# I need help with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascipt code something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads..........." ></script>
```

this script shows a banner. i want to use onClick event with this script without disturbing the banner click. is that possible?

Comment: It can be anything like :
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.clicmanager.fr/exe.php?c=17346&s=29646&t=1&q="></script>

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the banner is not wrapped in an iframe that is cross domain, but the question is...
onClick event on what? the banner? the page? another element?

use addEventListener/addEvent or a JS library to add the event. If this kills the banner be sure to take the banner's onclick property and add it as well to the banner.

Comment: Yes, a good idea to deploy listeners with a library, e.g. jQuery.

Comment: I have no idea of how to deploy a listener. Can you please guide me or show me some example? I want to open the banner page when someone clicks on a banner and also want to open a separate window on onclick that can be any url like www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Those scripts usually produce dynamic content via `document.write`. If you examine the resulting DOM (e.g., via Firebug in FireFox, or Dev Tools in Chrome, etc.), you can get an idea of what the resulting structure is. If there's a top-level image or link, you can hook it with a DOM2 handler ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) is the standard form; IE uses [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx) instead; [Javascript libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com) can help iron out the inconsistencies for you). That would let you see a click without disturbing its underlying action (provided you don't cancel the event, but you have to do that on purpose, so you should be okay.)

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Process that click through the handler, e.g.

`<a href="#" onclick="javascript:yourFunctionThatEventuallyDoesTheRedirect('URLToRedirect')"><!-- Banner image --></a>`

Comment: I want to open both javascript link and my own link that means total 2 windows will be open on click. My script : 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.clicmanager.fr/exe.php?c=17346&s=29646&t=1&q="></script>

should not get interrupt, i need a separate window open with this one

Comment: I am using the following code but it is not helping me..

<a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/','','location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=600');">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.clicmanager.fr/exe.php?c=17346&s=29646&t=1&q=">
</script>
</a>